# Known to this context

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb, cxf, maven-jaxb2-plugin

My Java RESTful web service (Spring 3.1.1 and CXF 2.5.2) prints to stdout on every request

```
SystemId Unknown; Line #-1; Column #-1; class X nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

sometimes multiple times. Note that no exception is thrown or that no messages are logged with regards to the error. The class in question is generated by the maven-jaxb2-plugin from an XSD that contains other definitions as well. The element used to define the data type is

```
<xsd:element name="x">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element name="y" type="y" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:attribute name="count" type="xsd:long" use="optional"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I have several XSDs that I compile that way, yet class X is the only ever associated with the error message. The generated class has the annotations

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "y"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "x")
```

How do I fix this issue and get rid of the error message?

Comment: How do you construct JAXB context? Provide your CXF configuration. In worse scenario you can use [`extraClass`](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/200809.mbox/%3C8DA58330BA060E41AB52B73294034EA601287100@amer-ems1.IONAGLOBAL.COM%3E) property of [`org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxb.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue.

Before I unmarshalled my XML, I ran it through an XSL transformation. I gave the processor the wrong destination context. No wonder that the class wasn't known to context!